# How to prove that the given value of x is less than a

Tags: inequality

This question originally stems from one of the problems I was solving in structural engineering.

So I have x which is given as,

$$x= \sqrt{\frac{L^2 - b^2}{3}}$$

Also I have,

$$L= a+b$$

$$a>b$$

In the above equations (and inequality) L, a, b are positive real numbers (they are actually lengths, in the original structural engineering problem)

I was investigating, is there any way to prove that x will be less than a?

PS- Please help me with the tags

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{(a+b)^2 - b^2}{3}} < a$ is equivalent to $2ab < 2 a^2$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $$\begin{aligned}x&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{a^{2}+2ab} \\ 
&< \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{a^{2}+2a\cdot a}\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Got it! Thank You Paras